# how to scroll a huge sprite horizontally

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scroll, width, sprite

I need to scroll a sprite horizontally, that I attach movieclips to at run time.
Once all the clips are attached, the width of Sprite is larger than Flash max width. It ends up being something like 18000 px wide.

Is there a smart way to simply update the clip's labels and create the ilusion of scrolling all the content? I wish the content was not so wide but it has to be.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code and the reason behind the 18000px would make it easier to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set coordinates of loaded clips as they should be, but actually add them only if they should be visible. When they go out of sight, remove them from sprite again.